# Get attribute from Restful XML without tags in client

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest, netbeans

I want to get the attribute value from XML output that is being created by my Rest Web Service but without the tags in my Java client. I tried XPath but it doesn't seem to work with URLs, only with XML files that are stored in the drive. And all the answers about XPath are specifically for stored XML files not online. I am using Netbeans. The concept is, web service takes two numbers and provides the sum as an XML. Webservice url that I use in this example `http://localhost:8080/WSDemo/rest/book/5/2`

Rest Web service

**ApplicationConfig.java**

```
package wbs;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("rest")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    addRestResourceClasses(resources);
    return resources;
}


private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
    resources.add(wbs.GenericResource.class);
}

}
```

**GenericResource.java**

```
package wbs;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Path("book")
public class GenericResource {

@Context

private UriInfo context;
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("{n1}/{n2}")
public String getSum(@PathParam ("n1") int a, @PathParam ("n2") int b) {
    int c = a+b;
    return "<Sum>" + c + "</Sum>";

}

}
```

**Client**

**Sum.java**

```
package restclient;

import javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;



public class Sum {
  private WebTarget webTarget;
  private Client client;
  private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/WSDemo/rest/";

  public Sum(){
    client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
    webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path("book");
  }

public <T> T getSum(Class<T> responseType, String n1, String n2) throws ClientErrorException {
    WebTarget resource = webTarget;
    resource = resource.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("{0}/{1}", new Object[]{n1, n2}));
    return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(responseType);
}

public void putXml(Object requestEntity) throws ClientErrorException {
    webTarget.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).put(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
}

public void close() {
    client.close();
}
}
```

**RestClient.java**

```
package com.emmanouil;

import restclient.Sum;

public class RestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sum client = new Sum();
    String response = client.getSum (String.class,"5" , "2");
    System.out.println(response);
    client.close();
    
}
}
```

**Output**

[image]

I want to clear the tags and get the result (7 in this case). Of course, I can trim the string or any other other similar way but it's something that I don't want to do.

Comment: Did you trying parsing the response to XML, and then use java.xml.xpath to extract it with /sum/

Comment: @aclokay Yes, but I couldn't figure a way to use the URL as an input instead of a file path. If you or anyone else can show me the way to use the web service XML URL in XPath, of course I will accept it an answer.